# A poem generator with a random function and animation with a simulation of a casual chat

Tags: python

I'm writing a poem generator from user inputs and a little bit of clever programming to appear the poem was generated from the conversation, this is a simplified version of it I am also learning OOP
and would like to implement classes in some way also, check it out ..

I tried writing it from scratch this is how far I got I received an error I didn't understand.

```html
# subject
one = input("What is your name?") #Jim
# verb
hears = input("what did you do today " + one + "??") #swim
# key animate i want this to go one dot then two dots then three and loop
# for a desired amount of time a random amount of seconds specifed inside code
# like 3 - 12 seconds (picking a random number between those numbers and animating
# animating for that time (like dot dot dot)
_for = print("...")
# Engage
_2for = input("What was that " + hears + " for?")
instance = print("That actually sounds pretty fun")
home = input("are you home yet ??")

# for instance, I want this to randomize these three (mirror1,2,3)
mirror = print("the rattling of a mirror")
_2mirror = print("the glimmer in your eye")
_3mirror = print("Your plants need watering")

#final poem (mirror would be a random secltions of the three mirrors)
print("" + one + "" + hears + " for instance " + mirror + "")
```

I got this error

```html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/singlefawn/Desktop/Our Realm/1997/Programs/random gallery/_sooseow_1_2.py", line 21, in <module>
    print("" + one + "" + hears + " for instance " + mirror + "")
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str

Process finished with exit code 1
```

The end should be like this

What is your name?Jim
what did you do today Jim??swim
...
What was that swim for?not sure
That actually sounds pretty fun
are you home yet ??no

## these shouldn't be showing the three mirrors need to be selected at # random, it will be the end of the final one-line poem

the rattling of a mirror
the glimmer in your eye
Your plants need watering

Jim swim for instace your plants need watering

Comment: `print()` returns `None`, so when you assign it to the variable `mirror` it is assigned `None`. And when you concatenate `None` and a string, you get the error you received.

Comment: Any help with the animate part)0

Answer (score 1):

I am new to programming so take my answer with a grain of salt. 
Right now your code is:

```
mirror = print("the rattling of a mirror")
_2mirror = print("the glimmer in your eye")
_3mirror = print("Your plants need watering")
```

I think you intended it to be:

```
mirror = "the rattling of a mirror"
_2mirror = "the glimmer in your eye"
_3mirror = "Your plants need watering"
```

Basically, the line that is giving you the error is seeing string + string + print(string).

Comment: Please properly format your answer and mind the case (`mirror` vs `Mirror`) as it matters on Python.

Comment: That is brilliant , we will be great programmers, let’s keep it up. Hopefully some more skilled cats will roll through with some of the more complex parts. I changed that part and that helped take out errors